# Saving internet icon then re-opening causes EOF with image4j

Tags: java, favicon, eof, ico

I'm currently working on a project where I'm attempting to download a .ico file, but for some strange reason, I can't seem to open it programmatically once downloaded. I can however, open the image saved using any image editor or viewer. My code:

```
public static BufferedImage parseImageLocal(String url) throws IOException {
        if (url.endsWith(".ico")) {
            return ICODecoder.read(new File(url)).get(0);
        } else if (url.endsWith(".bmp")) {
            return BMPDecoder.read(new File(url));

        } else {
            return ImageIO.read(new File(url));
        }
    }

    public static void saveImage(BufferedImage img, String path)
            throws IOException {

        File outputfile = new File(path.replace("http://", ""));
        File parent = outputfile.getParentFile();
        parent.mkdir();
        if (!outputfile.exists()) {
            outputfile.createNewFile();
        }
        if (path.endsWith(".ico")) {
            ICOEncoder.write(img, outputfile);
        } else if (path.endsWith(".bmp")) {
            BMPEncoder.write(img, outputfile);
        } else {
            ImageIO.write(img, "png", outputfile);
        }
    }
```

And this is how i download images from the internet:

```
public static BufferedImage parseImage(String url) throws IOException {
        URL dest = new URL(url);
        if (url.endsWith(".ico")) {
            return ICODecoder.read(dest.openStream()).get(0);
        } else if (url.endsWith(".bmp")) {
            return BMPDecoder.read(dest.openStream());

        } else {
            return ImageIO.read(dest);
        }
    }
```

The error is on this line:

```
return ICODecoder.read(new File(url)).get(0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It "seems" that you are trying to download the icon from the internet, but you are trying to treat the `URL` as a `File`.

Basically, this isn't going to be possible, `File` won't be able to resolve to an actual physical file.

Instead, you should be using [`ICODecoder#read(InputStream)`](http://image4j.sourceforge.net/javadoc/net/sf/image4j/codec/ico/ICODecoder.html#read(java.io.InputStream)) and [`URL#openStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream())

Something more like...

```
BufferedImage img = null;
InputStream is = null;
try {
    // url begin an instance of java.net.URL
    is = url.openStream();
    img = ICODecoder.read(is);
} finally {
   try {
       is.close();
   } catch (Exception exp) {
   }
}
return img;
```

**Updated with example**

A web resource is not a `File`, you can not access it as if they were, instead, you need to use the classes designed for interacting with the internet/network.

For example...

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import net.sf.image4j.codec.ico.ICODecoder;

public class ReadFavicon {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ReadFavicon();
    }

    public ReadFavicon() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                try {
                    BufferedImage img = readIcon(new URL("https://secure.gravatar.com/favicon.ico"));
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "My FAVICON", "Icon", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, new ImageIcon(img));
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public BufferedImage readIcon(URL url) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage img = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            // url begin an instance of java.net.URL
            is = url.openStream();
            List<BufferedImage> imgs = ICODecoder.read(is);
            img = imgs != null ? imgs.size() > 0 ? imgs.get(0) : null : null;
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (Exception exp) {
            }
        }
        return img;
    }

}
```

**Update with some more ideas**

Now.  I could be wrong, but when I ran your code, I ran into a serious of problems with the paths...

Let's assume the original url/path is `https://secure.gravatar.com/favicon.ico`, when you save the image, you do something like...

```
File outputfile = new File(path.replace("http://", ""));
File parent = outputfile.getParentFile();
parent.mkdir();
```

With our original path, this would result in a `outputfile` of `https://secure.gravatar.com/favicon.ico`, which is obviously wrong...

We can correct for this by using `path.replace("https://", "")` as well...

```
path = path.replace("http://", "");
path = path.replace("https://", "");

File outputfile = new File(path);
File parent = outputfile.getParentFile();
parent.mkdir();
```

Now, this results in a `outputfile` of `secure.gravatar.com/favicon.ico`.  I become a little unstuck, as I'm not sure if this is what you want...but it does work for me...

Now, when you read the file, you do something like this...

```
public static BufferedImage parseImage(String url) throws IOException {
    URL dest = new URL(url);
    if (url.endsWith(".ico")) {
        return ICODecoder.read(dest.openStream()).get(0);
    } else if (url.endsWith(".bmp")) {
        return BMPDecoder.read(dest.openStream());

    } else {
        return ImageIO.read(dest);
    }
}
```

Now, with no evidence to the contray, I have to assume the `url` has not changed and is still `https://secure.gravatar.com/favicon.ico`...this means that `new File("https://secure.gravatar.com/favicon.ico")` will produce an invalid file reference

So, again, I parsed the input...

```
url = url.replace("https://", "");
url = url.replace("http://", "");
File outputfile = new File(url);
String parentPath = outputfile.getParent();
String name = outputfile.getName();

url = parentPath + File.separator + name;
```

Which produces `secure.gravatar.com\favicon.ico`

This all downloaded, wrote and read without error.

Comment: I save the image, store it, then reopen it

Comment: What's the source path.

Comment: full path or relative to the project?

Comment: C:\Users\Dylan\Google Drive\folders, zips, rars, etc\java stuff\Spidor\favicons\icon.ico

Comment: So the Icon is local your system?  Aren't favicons pngs?

Comment: wait you want where i'm downloading it, or where i'm storing it for reopening

Comment: I want to know where you are reading them from, how you are reading them

Comment: I have no problems downloading the image(I edited the original question a bit), but I can not reopen them with code once I've saved them from the internet.